# Night skiing in Switzerland

Tags: switzerland, skiing

I'm looking for any ski resort (anywhere in Switzerland) with night(after 6pm) skiing on Sundays. If anybody aware of any such a resorts, please share a link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you found so far from your research? Because just googling the question shows results.  In fact the first result shows 75 resorts with Night Skiing.

Comment: I found a lot of stuff, on Friday, Wensday, Tuesday. None of them (Davon,  Flumserberg, Zermatt,  Lenzerheide, Greendewald, etc) offer Sunday night skiing. Not to mention website like this is pure crap https://www.bergfex.com/luzern-vierwaldstaettersee/nachtskilauf/ it basically doesn't show the right info

Comment: You should add what you found to your question because that shows that you have done prior research.

Comment: Why would you want to ski on a Sunday night? Usually by Sunday afternoon the slopes are already crap...

Comment: @KristvanBesien where I go in Austria they prepare them again before night skiing. But as it is in Austria and they don't do Sunday night skiing I will just comment.